# Changing Disk Allocation for Ubuntu on Dual-Boot System

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage

When I first installed Ubuntu, I had a new PC with Windows 7 installed.  It was my first installation of Ubuntu so I only allocated 45% of the disk for Ubuntu.  Now I find that I have been using Ubuntu exclusively so I would like to change the allocation of the disk so Ubuntu has say 75% of the disk and Win. 7 25%.  Is there a way to do this without reformatting the disk.  I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by downloading the [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) Live CD or USB.

Boot into GParted and resize your Ubuntu partition however you see fit.